# design a django model so that we can have have a category field and the category can have unknown no of attributes

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I want to create a web app for a medical lab and i want to store the patient's information with the type of test they have done. The problem here is that a patient can do multiple tests and the tests can have unknown number of fields to it. I want the test category as well as the test to be manually added. I'm stuck in designing the Django model.
What is the best approach to this problem? Sorry if this is a noob question.

Comment: Please, share your code here.

Comment: @hamedbaziyad I haven't written any code. I need help designing the model.